# Prisma date object does not pass Zod date validation

Tags: date, types, prisma, zod

I have the following code:

```js
export const getSales = procedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
  const sales = await ctx.prisma.sale.findMany({
    where: { deletedAt: null },
  })

  return salesSelectOutput.parse(sales)
})
```

**saleSelectOutput**:
`saleSelectOutput` is a zod validation made by changing/omitting some values from `saleSchema` which is also used to create a `createSaleInput`.
`salesSelectOutput` is just the array version of `saleSelectOutput`.

### The issue

This code has no issues running except for one validation failure on `sales.[n].dateOfSale`

```json
"code": "invalid_type",
"expected": "date",
"received": "object",
"path": [
  "dateOfSale"
],
"message": "please input a proper date"
```

I tried checking what dateOfSale was and it was a type `object` with the following value:

```
2024-02-28T08:09:50.339Z
```

I have similar issues on other locations so something that only fixes this case scenario such as the following is not an option

```js
  return salesSelectOutput.parse({...sales, dateOfSale: new Date(dateOfSale)})
```

#### Question

What is the best way to let zod accept prisma's object as a date or change the value before validating it?